# Selenium driver - not able to close the popup, element not found is the main issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, popup

Using selenium find element (using xpath) method to close the popup but it is not able to detect it.
time.sleep(10)
driver.fin_element(By.XPATH,"XPATH").close()

I have also use time.sleep and webdriver wait methods but it not working
Website: [www.multcloud.com](http://www.multcloud.com)

time.sleep(10)
webdriver wait
ec. Element traceable method

Also try Find elements but it is showing empty list.
Tried find element using class_name,xpath, full xpath,cs locator,link text

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
driver.get("https://www.multcloud.com/")
sleep(4)
driver.switch_to.frame("layui-layer-iframe1")

You could use explicit wait in the place of sleep
sleep(3)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"((//div[@class='sale-close-img'])[2])")

button.click()
```

**Imports**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

[image]

Comment: received message: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (852, 43)

Comment: also tried `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: @user-26 I have updated the XPATH in the above answer could try that and let me know if that works for you

Comment: `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="layui-layer-iframe1"]"}`

Comment: but the same is working for me

Comment: can you please show me how me how you are generating the selnium web driver

Comment: I'm using Webdriver Manager you can check the above screenshot